Создать exe используя Maven
Написал приложение на java и хочу, чтобы оно запускалось на любом компьютере в не зависимости от того установлена ли на нем java или нет. Также хотел бы добавить иконк. Как я могу сделать это используя Maven? Я нашел Maven Launch4j Plugin, но не нашел нормальной документации к нему

а документация, написанная разработчиками, ненормальная? p.s. да и без jre вам же в любом случае не обойтись. кто ж ваш байт-код будет интерпретировать, если вы не тащите с собой всё это хозяйство?

Так разве нельзя добавить стандартный JRE в файл?

Джава байт код это машинный код для виртуального процессора/машины под названием jvm, только он может его выполнять, и по-любому jre должен быть установлен, а что бы он запускался на любом компьютере без его установки можно в exe запаковать jre, правда это может быть не удобно, так как весит она 200 - 300 мб, а если ты в каждую программу будешь паковать этот jre, то получает каждая программа по 200 мб весит...

Поэтому самым лучшим вариантом будет указать ссылку на нужную jre, и что бы пользователь его установил


Для начала скачайте официальный JDK здесь.

Выберите версию JDK под ваш проект,например, "JDK 21", и выберите "Windows"

затем скачайте x64 Compressed Archive



Создайте папку в любом месте и назовите ее под ваш проект, например My Programs, откройте архив jdk-xx_windows-x64_bin.zip.

Это будет папка jdk-xx.x.x.

Распакуйте эту папку в My Programs и переименуйте папку в jre.



Теперь скомпилируйте ваш проект в jar файл и переместите его в My Programs.

Запустите приложение Launch4j

Output file выберите папку той же My Programs и название вашего exe, например WindowHelloWorld.exe.

В поле jar выберите ваш jar файл

icon выберите ваше иконку, если у вас есть картинка в формате png или jpg, конвертируйте ее в ico.

Теперь нажмите на вкладку classpath

поставьте галочку custom classpath

В поле Main-Class укажите путь к вашему классу, например org.example.Main.

Нажмите на вкладку JRE, в JRE paths напишите jre/.

Наконец, нажмите build, сохраните конфигурацию в My Programs и ваш exe файл будет готов.




